# Pandas groupby index is incorrect

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I may be misunderstanding what the `pd.GroupBy` function does, but I believe this should assert `True.` Why is it asserting `False`?

```py
a = pd.DataFrame([range(3)]*3,index=map(str, range(3))).T
a.iloc[:,0] = [10, 11, 11]

a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: print(x.index))

indexes = a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: x.index)
print(indexes)

index_lengths = a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: len(x.index))
print(index_lengths)

indexes_lengths = a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: x.index).apply(len)
print(indexes_lengths)

assert indexes_lengths.equals(index_lengths), "Apply indexes are returning the wrong index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe bug, but if convert index to `list` all working nice:

```
indexes = a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: list(x.index))
print(indexes)
0
10       [0]
11    [1, 2]
dtype: object

indexes_lengths = a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: list(x.index)).apply(len)
print(indexes_lengths)
0
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64

index_lengths = a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: len(x.index))
print(index_lengths)
0
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a bug in `apply`. If you still want output as list of `index` objects, just create new index object for each group by adding `.copy`

```
a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: x.index.copy())

Out[706]:
0
10       Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
11    Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
dtype: object
```

`len` of `index` seems not suffering this bug

```
a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: len(x.index))

Out[707]:
0
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64
```

Only when applying directly to `index`, this bug appears. So, adding `.copy` will return as you desire

```
a.groupby('0').apply(lambda x: x.index.copy()).apply(len)

Out[708]:
0
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64
```